# jquery getScript function never fails?

Tags: jquery, ajax, getscript

The jQuery getScript fail function is never called. See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/getsetbro/8xNMs/

```
$.getScript("http://api.jquery.com/scripts/jquery.NO-SUCH-FILE.js").done(function() {
    console.log('yep');
}).fail(function() {
    console.log('fail function does not fire fine');
});
```

And the complete function is never called:
http://jsfiddle.net/getsetbro/ns6yQ/

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'script',
    async:false,
    cache:false,
    success: function(result) {
        console.log('SUCCESS');
    },
    error: function(result) {
        console.log('ERROR');
    },
    complete: function(result) {
        console.log('COMPLETE');
    }
})
```

Oh, and in IE it actually fires SUCCESS and COMPLETE when it should have failed. =[

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.fail` is not working for cross-domain request.

```
// Bind script tag hack transport
jQuery.ajaxTransport( "script", function(s) {

    // This transport only deals with cross domain requests
    if ( s.crossDomain ) {
    ...
    script = document.createElement( "script" );
```

Script element fires no errors and such.

But it's ok for same domain. http://jsfiddle.net/8xNMs/2/

Answer (score 3):

cross-domain .fail & .always work with jQuery 2.0

```
$.getScript("http://api.jquery.com/scripts/NO-SUCH-FILE.js")
  .done(function() {
    console.log("done fired");
  }).fail(function() {
    console.log("fail fired");
  }).always(function() {
    console.log("always fired");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c2gyy/1/

Comment: Edited code to just use `console.log` because the references to Toastr are broken. http://jsfiddle.net/4s5183cw/1/