# Protocol relative URL method for jQuery UI using native input type="date"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using the following function, this script asks the browser whether `<input type="date">` is available natively. If not, it will load jQuery UI from CDN.

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    // Date Picker with fallback
    // http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-date
    var i = document.createElement("input");
    i.setAttribute("type", "date");
    if (i.type == "text") {

        // No native date picker support :(
        // Use jQuery UI to create one then dynamically replace that <input> element.
        var jQueryUICSS = document.createElement('link');
        jQueryUICSS.href = "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css";
        jQueryUICSS.rel = "stylesheet";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jQueryUICSS);

        $.getScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js", function() {
            $.datepicker.setDefaults(
                $.extend($.datepicker.regional[''])
            );
        });
    }
});
```

What I'd like to do is make sure there's a local fallback for both CSS and JS using the Protocol Relative method that [Paul Irish defined](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) but using the updated version according to [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html#L27-L28) similar to this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

In the original example, Javascript is creating a `link` element that solely points to jquery's website. I'm not quite sure how to write the 2nd line of this protocol relative method and creating it using javascript.

Similarly, jQuery UI js file is being added by the `getScript()` method. How do I add a local version of this file that will still allow `$.datepicker()` to load as intended? I had to use `getScript()` because if I didn't the datepicker would throw a console error saying it's undefined.

How would I include this fallback method for local files into the code I've already written out?

Comment: Use the error callback of the first `getScript` to load the local version?

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I don't know how to write this. I'm not strong writing javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Promise pattern](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
$.getScript("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js")
  .then(null, function handleError() {
      console.log("first try failed, loading local version");
      return $.getScript("js/vendor/jquery-ui.min.js");
  }).done(function() {
      console.log("succeeded to load jQuery UI");
      $.datepicker.setDefaults(
          $.extend($.datepicker.regional[''])
      );
  }).fail(function(_, status, error) {
      console.error("both attempts to load jQuery UI failed", status, error);
  });
```

However, it seems that in some jQuery versions the [`$.getScript` function never fails on crossdomain scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476497/jquery-getscript-function-never-fails) so you will probably need to use a timeout for that.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I got caught up yesterday and couldn't reply back so quickly. I tested the error out by misspelling the googleapis url. I don't see a script for the local version of jQuery UI either. For some reason, it still displays the console log saying succeeded to load jQuery UI.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're using an older version of jQuery 1.7.2. After reading jQuery's API info for `.then()`, I took out the word null. That made the first console log error message appear. But the local js isn't returned.